# Is calling a method within an abstract method common use?

Tags: java, abstract

I'm currently developing a Menu structure with a
Main class, a Menu Class and a MenuEntry class.

The Menu class is abstract, but only has a single abstract method.
MenuEntry also has a single abstract method.

The Main class has methods like "shutdown", "pushState" "popState" etc.

Is it okay/common use to call shutDown() from the main class within the instatiation of the Menu/MenuEntry?

```
public class Main
{
  public void init()
  {
    Menu m = new Menu()
    {
      public void abortAction()
      {
        shutDown();
      }
    };
    m.addEntry(new MenuEntry()
    {
      public void activate()
      {
        start();
      }
    });
  }
  public void shutDown()
  {
    //cleanup etc.
  }

  public void start()
  {
    //start here.
  }
  /*
   * other methods 
   */


}
```

---

```
public abstract class Menu
{
  //...
  void addEntry(MenuEntry e)
  {
    //...
  }
  public abstract void abortAction();
}




public abstract class MenuEntry
{
  //...
  public abstract void activate();
}
```

It somehow does look ugly though.

Comment: Comment to your title: An abstract method (a method with the `abstract` keyword) doesn't have any code (not allowed, fails to compile if you try), so you can't do anything from within it.

Comment: Sure,  but I had no idea how to name it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse code in `shutDown` or `start` this is perfectly fine,

But do not expect to have the internal state of the Menu or MenuEntity inside these methods (these methods will have access to the state of the `Main` class), unless you pass a reference to these methods.

Other than that, in my opinion this is fine. But it depends on what you want do do,